# Iterating files in order of name, Python

Tags: python, file, iteration

I am iterating a bunch of files like so:

```
for file in glob('./*.dat'):
            print file
```

And the output is always the following:

```
./SAN0.dat
./SAN4.dat
./SAN1.dat
./SAN2.dat
./SAN3.dat
./SAN5.dat
./SAN6.dat
./SAN7.dat
```

How can I iterate them in order of their name, (meaning `SAN1.dat` would be second, for example)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
for file in sorted(glob('./*.dat')):
```

Comment: Note that if the number of files is greater than 10 this won't work, since `"SAN10.dat"` would come before `"SAN2.dat"`. In this case you need to create a function that converts the number in the filename to an `int`, and call `sorted` with the `key` argument set to this function.

Answer (score 2):

```
lst = glob('./*.dat')
lst.sort()
```

Answer (score 0):

Following is the easiest way to iterate the files in order of filenames in python-

```
import os
for file in sorted(os.listdir(path))
```